# MySQL to DQL - Doctrine

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, dql

I am trying create a query in Doctrine and am having trouble. I have figured out the needed query in mysql but cannot seems to convert it over to DQL.

Here is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT p.id, count(p.id) as count
  FROM pear as p
  JOIN vote as v ON v.pear_id = p.id
  GROUP BY p.id
  ORDER BY count DESC
) as t
GROUP BY t.icon_id;
```

If I do the following:

```
return $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT * FROM (SELECT p.id, count(p.id) as count from pear as p JOIN vote as v ON v.pear_id = p.id GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY count DESC) as t GROUP BY t.icon_id'
);
```

I get the following Error:

> `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration | PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got '*'`

There may be a better way to achieve these results.

I have four tables:

- Icons
- Pears
- Songs
- Votes

Pears match Icons to Songs. Votes are a vote on a Pair.

I am trying to find the top pear for every Icon. My logic was to find all pears for an icon and group them by the number of votes. I then need to limit this to only return the top pear for each icon.

My desired end result is a list of Pear objects, 1 per Icon.

Comment: change `*` to `t` which would be parsed by Doctrine's lexer as an `IdentificationVariable`

Comment: Adam, Thanks for editing the format and the suggestion, I will give it a try